# execute java -jar name.jar -p myproject by maven

Tags: maven-plugin

by command line in the directory of myproject I run java -jar cnesreport.jar -p myproject and it works. Now I want to execute a mvn exec: exec or exec: java and I do not know how I should modify the pom.

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.6.0</version>
 <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>java</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
      </executions>

  <configuration>
     <executable>java</executable>
     <arguments>
         <argument>-jar</argument>            
             <argument>C:/Users/jvegacas/git/web/web/target</argument>
                    <argument>-p</argument>
         <argument>C:/Users/jvegacas/git/web</argument>  
         </arguments>
  </configuration>

    </plugin>
```

Command execution failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `<goal>exec</goal>` (since `java`:

   > execute(s) Java programs in the same VM

   )
2. `<executable>java</executable>` could work, but only when it is on the `PATH`
3. arguments, like this:

   ```
   <arguments>
       <argument>-jar</argument>
       <!-- !! -->
       <argument>target/cnesreport.jar</argument>
       <argument>-p</argument>
       <!-- if you mean rather the "location" than the "name", then:
         <argument>.</argument>
       or <argument>${baseDir}</argument>
       -->
       <argument>myproject</argument>
   </arguments>
   ```

[@See](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/)

Comment: Thanks! I have an error: [ERROR] com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 12 path $, however it is due to another issue. As you indicated, it would work for me, thank you.